# How to generate random values (multinomial?)

Tags: excel, variables, random, statistics

I have four groups with individual proportions: p1, p2, p3, p4. Taking a random sample from this, the sum of the four values should equal `20` for each generation.

I have seen how to create four random values that sum to a number, but how do I factor in that they have these initial probabilities of being chosen?

*******Maybe I should elaborate on the question. There are four groups of candy being chosen to create a package of 20. The proportions are 20%, 25%, 30%, and 25% of the candies on an assembly line. Candies are selected randomly from this process and placed in the packages of 20 pieces. I am to simulate the process of creating 1000 of these packages. All 1000 generations should add up to 20.****

Comment: **Help us to help you.** edit your question to include a listing of your data and a single "good" result.

Answer (score 2):

Just wondering if we are talking about something like the below?

```
    Perc    =RAND()         =B2*C2          =D2/SUM($D$2:$D$5)  =E2*20
P1  5%      0.168440417     0.008422021     0.026888651         0.537773022
P2  15%     0.23130968      0.034696452     0.110773983         2.215479657
P3  25%     0.424406873     0.106101718     0.338746737         6.774934746
P4  55%     0.2981786       0.16399823      0.523590629         10.47181258
```

Where the formulas are pasted in row 2, and copied down?

After seeing the edits to your question, I'm thinking maybe the below would be better?

F3:Y1003 has the formula: `=RANDBETWEEN(1,20)`

A3 has the formula: `=COUNTIFS($F5:$Y5,">=1",$F5:$Y5,"<=4")` (equivalent of 20%)

B3 has the formula: `=COUNTIFS($F5:$Y5,">=5",$F5:$Y5,"<=9")` (equivalent of 25%)

C3 has the formula: `=COUNTIFS($F5:$Y5,">=10",$F5:$Y5,"<=15")` (equivalent of 30%)

D3 has the formula: `=COUNTIFS($F5:$Y5,">=16",$F5:$Y5,"<=20")` (equivalent of 25%)

Then copy A3:D3 down to A1003:D1003.

[image]

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. At least this is the process of how to compute one such set of numbers. I need to generate 1000.

Comment: At first I was generating three rand() for 1000 rows then denoting that as my first three proportions. My last proportion I found my subtracting the sum of the others from 20, but my problem is that I ended up with negative numbers for 30 or so of my generations. Is there a way to generalize your method to create 1000 of those?

Comment: The edited solution is assuming that the assembly line creates a "generation" that is "independent" of the one before.  Otherwise this would need to be adjusted.  I hope the fraction equivalent to the percentages makes sense as well.